# Does Bulk Insert have an opportunity with accent grave characters?

Tags: sql-server

If I do this, it works correctly with plain old varchar, so I don't think it's a nVarchar problem:

```
declare @RAM TABLE(
Descr Varchar(128)
)
INSERT INTO @RAM(Descr) VALUES('De La Crème')
SELECT * FROM @RAM
```

But I'm having trouble importing the same data with a Bulk Insert.

Q: Is there a setting that I'm missing to allow accent grave?

Comment: What is the problem when you try to use bulk insert?  An error?  Mangled data?  Something else?

Comment: The problem is that the character doesn't look like the right character.

Comment: There's no need to use nVarchar in this example.  It works using plain ole Varchar.

Comment: Oh.  I think mine is latin, and it's working for me.  I don't have to worry about other collations.

Answer (score 0):

Your question connected not with `Bulk Insert` (actually, there is no `Bulk Insert` in your code) or `INSERT`, but with data types. You need to use [nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and `N` in front of the string constant which define it as a UNICODE value.

```
declare @RAM TABLE(
Descr nvarchar(128)
)
INSERT INTO @RAM(Descr) VALUES(N'De La Crème')
SELECT * FROM @RAM
```